# How to keep multiple selection of rows in datagrid after double click in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I selected some rows in datagrid programatically then When I edit some field in DataGrid by double clicking I loose all my multi-selected rows. How to keep multiselection of rows after double clicking on the cell.I distinguished single click and double click by using setInterval and made datagrid editable on doubleclick.When i select multiple rows with ctrl key then double clicking on the cell multiselection is perfectly working.But when i set selected rows programatically then double clicking on the cell multiselection is getting lost.Can any one please tell me how to keep multi selected rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, have you tried it? (You can't know exact double click length on target machine.)
To keep the selection, you can just store indices of those rows in an array and restore selection after double click.

Comment: Alxx thanks for ur reply. I did that but the problem is when double click at first the selected items got deselected and again it got selected but that doesnt looks nice.So i am looking for any better way to maintain those selected rows highlighted always.

Comment: "Doesn't look nice" is like they lost focus (grey instead of blue?)

Comment: ya exactly they lost focus .. i want to keep that focus

Comment: Thanks for ur answer i did what u said.. I stored the instances in one model and assigned after double click.